# How to avoid that my server restarts every time I commit something?

Tags: openshift

I have 3 cartridges: PHP 5.4, MySQL 5.5 and phpMyAdmin 4.0. Every time I commit any change to my openshift, I see that my website is down because Apache is restarting but, is this really necessary? Is there any way to avoid it to restart everytime?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Today I discovered how to hot-deploy my application. Link: [openshift.com/blogs/hot-deploying-php-on-openshift](http://openshift.com/blogs/hot-deploying-php-on-openshift)

Definition of hot-deploy: [Hot-deployable services are those which can be added to or removed from the running server. It is the ability to change ON-THE-FLY what’s currently deployed without redeploying it.](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HotVsColdDeployment?_sscc=t)

Other information: [openshift.com/kb/kb-e1057-how-can-i-deploy-my-application-without-having-to-restart-it](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1057-how-can-i-deploy-my-application-without-having-to-restart-it)